# Analog of java.util.Map#computeIfAbsent for scala.Option

Tags: scala, option-type

I have a variable of type [Option[…]](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) in Scala.

I need to:

- if it already has a value — return the value;
- if it doens't have a value yet — fill it with a value from some predefined supplier-method and return the value.

I.e. it should act like a cache for some longly-calculated supplier-method.

Of course, I can do it in a dumb way:

```
var cache: Option[X]
…
{
    if (cache.isEmpty) cache = Some(supplier())
    cache.get
}
```

But I believe that there should be some simpler one-liner in the style of Java [Map#computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Is there?

Comment: @jwvh, how that would return a value? I will need to write `{ cache = cache.getOrElse(Some(supplier()); cache.get }` in that case anyway.

Comment: True, and therein lies another problem with mutable data elements in Scala: assignments are statements, not expressions, thus assigning and returning have to be 2 separate steps. And `getOrElse()` won't work anyway because the `get` and the `else` are 2 different types. My bad.

Comment: @jwvh, hmm, I've just realized that Scala's `Option` is designed to be immutable (unlike Java's `Map`), so a method I'd like to see can't exist even theoretically. (IMHO, a language designed for extensive usage of immutable structures should support `ref`/`inout`-mode function parameters, but Scala doesn't.) Anyway, I think I'll let the question hang for some more time.

Comment: Your requirements, and example, don't make much sense to me. The call to `supplier()` can only be made once since whatever it returns will get wrapped in a `Some()` and thus can never be `.isEmpty` again. So why not make it a `lazy val`? Then it would get populated, not when defined, but if/when it is first referenced, later in the code, and retain that value thereafter.

Comment: @jwvh, yikes! `lazy val`! That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in one line because you have to do an assignment to update `cache` and then an extraction to get the value:

```
cache = cache orElse Some(supplier())
cache.get
```

Assignment returns `Unit` so you can't use the result of the assignment to read the value.

---

This code pattern is sometimes called "memoizing" and there are lots of examples of generic code for this on stackoverflow and elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

After some thinking, I've realized that such a thing couldn't exist in Scala for `Option` even theoretically. Because `Option` is designed to be immutable (unlike Java `Map`), so it won't have methods that update update it's value (even more — `None` and `Some` are different subclasses of `Option`). Neither we can write some external auxiliary method like `def getOrFill[T](ref cache: Optional[T])(supplier: => T): T`, because Scala doesn't support `ref` (in-out) parameters.

Probably the best thing that we can do is to create a separate class for caching (wrapper over `Option`):

- Variant 1:

  ```
  class Cache[T] {
    def getOrFill(supplier: => T): T = {
      if (value.isEmpty) value = Some(supplier)
      value.get
    }
    private var value: Option[T] = None
  }
  ```

  then

  ```
  var cache = new Cache[X]
  …
  cache.getOrFill(supplier())
  ```
- Variant 2 — if the same supplier is used throughout the whole life of cache (the most probable scenario):

  ```
  class Cache[T](supplier: => T) {
    def getOrFill: T = {
      if (value.isEmpty) value = Some(supplier)
      value.get
    }
    private var value: Option[T] = None
  }
  ```

  then

  ```
  var cache = new Cache[X](supplier())
  …
  cache.getOrFill
  ```

Notice: I didn't think about variances for the code above too much (maybe variances should be changed).

Comment: Scala does support ref parameters, all parameters are by-ref unless they are marked as by-name.

Comment: @Tim, I meant the other terminology — I meant "by ref" as opposite of "by value" (i.e. whether a calling function sees modifications of parameter changed by a called function), not immediate calculation versus delayed calculation.

Comment: My point is that you *can* write the "auxiliary method" that you describe. You would pass the `Optional` object to the function and mutate it in the function, and those changes would be visible outside the function.

Comment: @Tim, sorry, but I can't. Neither Scala supports in-out parameters, nor the `Option` class is designed to be mutable. If I'm wrong, please show me the example (although my practical interest is fully satisfied with jwvh's mention of `lazy val`s, my theoretical interest is open for your information).